# How do I use jQuery to return a record from an XML file where the node name is duplicated?

Tags: jquery, xml, georss

How do I go about getting just one of the records from the XML file below using jQuery.  The node name  is duplicated in the XML data file:

```
    <category label="Certainty" scheme="masas:category:certainty" term="Observed" />
    <category label="Category" scheme="masas:category:category" term="Transport" />
    <category label="Severity" scheme="masas:category:severity" term="Minor" />
    <category label="Status" scheme="masas:category:status" term="Actual" />
    <category label="Icon" scheme="masas:category:icon" term="ems/incident/roadway/roadwayClosure" />strong text
```

This is the code I am currently using to retrieve text from the XML file:

icon =  $(this).find("[nodeName='category']").text();

Comment: Depends how you want to choose the record of interest; by index or by label for example.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to filter for category label = icon, then retrieve the value of "term" (ems/incident/roadway/roadwayClosure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
icon = $(this).find("[nodeName='category']").filter("[label='icon']").attr('term');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('category[label=Icon]', this).attr('term')
```